# C# Drag and Drop one picture box into another picture box

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag and drop one picture box into another picture box.
please help me!
thanks
Best Regards

Comment: Please specify your platform and provide some code that you may have written to make this work.

Comment: Drop image into picture-box OR Drop picture-box into a picture-box.

Comment: hi.i want drag an image from picturebox1 and drop it into picturebox2 while that image will be move with moues until Mouse_Down Event Occure and image placed in picturebox2 thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this http://www.codeguru.com/Csharp/Csharp/cs_syntax/controls/article.php/c5865

**Upadated:**
Do a trick

```
    bool holdsImage = false;
    Control currentControl = null;
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        holdsImage = true;           
    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentControl = pictureBox2;
    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentControl = null;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (holdsImage && currentControl==pictureBox2)
        {
            pictureBox2.Image = pictureBox1.Image;
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
        }
        holdsImage = false;
        currentControl = null;
    }
```

Problem is that I am unable to find AllowDrop property in PictureBox else it will be easy to implement by `DoDragDrop()`

Comment: thanks for your Answer. But i want drag and drop once imgae to another picturebox with mouse

Comment: To get AllowDrop to work use...
((Control)pictureBox1).AllowDrop = true;
Works but a bit weird why not straight forward.