# drag and drop picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am coding a simple solitaire game just for fun and a bit of practice but do not know how to drag and drop a card in a specified position. 
The card itself was set as an image in a picturebox and I guess what I want to do is to drag this picturebox and drop it in a specified position at another picturebox location.

Any advice perhaps.

Kind regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [drag and drop winform controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280164/drag-and-drop-winform-controls)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Drag and Drop one picture box into another picture box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447814/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-one-picture-box-into-another-picture-box)

Comment: There are a lot of articles written on drag and drop.  Once you understand how it works it really isn't that hard, and the articles are great.  But for a beginner they are complex and difficult to understand.  You will have to pick an article read it, try it, read it again, try it again, eventually it will click, though I know its frustrating.  It's almost like drag and drop was designed to be difficult, though to be honest I don't know how I would make it better.

Comment: PS: Intellisense does not expose the AllowDrop for a PictureBox, but you can mannually type it  pb.AllowDrop=True

Answer (score 3):

Just add:

```
myPixtureBox.AllowDrop = true;
```

Note: This is not available at design time.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.allowdrop(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on the topic.

[A Simple Drag And Drop How To Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9017/A-Simple-Drag-And-Drop-How-To-Example)