# Drag-and-drop from PictureBox to another is not working

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

Here is my code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pBox1.AllowDrop = true;
    }

    private void pBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var bmp = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
        pBox1.Image = bmp;
        pBox1.Size = new Size(100, 100);
    }

    private void pBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DoDragDrop(pBox2.Image, DragDropEffects.Move) == DragDropEffects.Move)
        {
            pBox2.Image = null;
        }
    }
```

pBox1 is the pictureBox that I would like to drag into, and pBox2 is the pictureBox I would like to drag from.  The error I get is an object reference not set to instance of object error, on the line "if(DoDragDrop...." within the MouseDown method.

Comment: You are missing the DragEnter event that allows the d&d to actually happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you have listed is the entire code listing, you are never setting pBox2.Image to an Image, which would cause the exception.  May want to add:

```
private void pBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(pBox2.Image != null)
        {
            if (DoDragDrop(pBox2.Image, DragDropEffects.Move) == DragDropEffects.Move)
            {
                pBox2.Image = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

To initialize the pBox2 to an image of some sort...

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        pBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"YourFilePath");
    }
```

***Edit***
Just a note, this gets rid of your exception, but still does not implement drag drop properly.  I am playing with it and will get back with you if I find a proper solution.

***Edit***

Possible duplicate to the following link:

[Stack Overflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447814/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-one-picture-box-into-another-picture-box)

I got it working using the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        pictureBox2.AllowDrop = true;
        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\TitleBar.jpg");
    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox2.Image != null)
        {
            pictureBox2.DoDragDrop(pictureBox2.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
            pictureBox2.Image = null;
        }

    }

    private void pictureBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    }
}
```